How much total energy is available in/on the Earth?
A worldbuilding question.
Consider if the Earth is isolated from the rest of the universe. It happens instantaneously with current technology. However, over a long time span different technologies can emerge to tap the available energy.
Once isolated, the sun and everything else is gone. All that is available to the survivors is the potential and kinetic energy of the earth and moon.
Sources of energy include

kinetic energy in spinning Earth
energy in moon orbit
thermal energy in earth core (heat can be dissipated into space)
potential energy in radioactive decay
potential chemical energy (oxidation, biosphere, etc)

In the short term, the survivors will tap the energy using existing technology constrained by the immediate emergency. Longer term, they will work through other sources of energy to go though survival, then rebirth, then expansion as a closed civilization. The question below, is to help help understand the size of the civilization possible and sustainable before needing to convert remaining mattering into energy.
How much energy is available for the survivors to used to restart and build a civilization in that environment?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Frame Challenge
The absolute quantity that could be extracted over an indefinite timeline doesn't matter, the immediately available rate of extraction is too low for survivors to access most of the energy that is theoretically there before they die. The heat budget is going to lose the ~1.73x1017W solar energy instantly. A decent model for what happens next is what happens to desert temperatures at night, they drop ~42°C in 12 hours or less. The surface of the world is going to freeze solid to a depth of several metres within, at most, 48 hours.
The only people who might survive past those first days are going to be in deep mines where the ground heat stops them freezing immediately. However they don't have long to live, the ventilation and pumping systems they rely upon to survive are on the surface so they're still going to die shortly after the surface freeze down.
Life will survive for a long time in ecosystems that don't have any solar energy inputs, i.e. deep ocean vent ecosystems, but people won't be around long enough to systematically exploit remaining energy sources/stores.

A valid challenge, but I could wish the OP ansewered my comment question. Why is this number needed in the first place? I can't even imagine calculating the energy potential for, e.g. technological improvements to wind turbines.

@JBH Wind pretty much stops when the sun stops creating thermal flows, ditto ocean currents, if you could stop the world freezing solid in two days flat, and you'd need some Clarketech, the only energy sources left are the kinetic energy of rotation in the Earth-Moon system and radioactive decay, either geologically or artificially expressed and burning the biosphere fast or slow. In theory those are relatively calculable but you're right to ask "why"?

Nothing in the question states whether the catastrophe happens immediately without any warning, or there is at least some short preparation time. If there is some preparation time, there is still no way with current technology to access more than a tiny fraction of the available energy, but given enough preparation time, we could build some bunkers where many could survive for a long long time, especially if they are equipped with nuclear reactors, and/or have access to geothermal vents and plenty of water.

Frame challenge challenge: 1) polar regions in a half year long night go at most until -80C. 2) until you can heat, you live. Deep mountain bunkers have very likely a lot of fuel. 3) Earths internal heat generates a 0.42W/m^2 continuous heat transfer on the surface, very likely we won't have a liquid air atmosphere soon. There will be only dark and deadly cold.

@GraySheep 1. Yes that's kind of the point. 2. ? first sentence doesn't make sense. there are only a few such bunkers and they relay on being able to draw in air at a reasonable temperature, at severely negative temperatures the vents will freeze up no matter how much fuel is available, the existing infrastructure doesn't use nuclear energy. 3. I hadn't thought about, and didn't think I had mentioned, the atmosphere at all, I'm just thinking that soil and water will freeze solid to reasonable depth very quickly.

Question is, how far can they go. I think, on the current technology, such an even would quickly kill us all without preparation. Probably there are bunkers to survive a little part of the humanity a nuclear winter. For such an event, we did not prepare at all.
However, actually it is quite easy to calculate the total energy what we could extract from the Earth. This energy is terribly big. We have no chance to even start to work it.
If there is proton decay and we can use it
If there is proton decay, it is theoretically possible to convert matter into antimatter. Reason is very simple, protons decay to positrons plus energy. And positrons annihillate with the electrons to energy.
(More clearly: not into energy but into photons, but the net result is photons.)
So you can "evaporate" the Earth on this way. From all gram of Earth matter, you can extract the energy of an entry-level nuclear bomb.
That is a theoretical optimum - with our current technology, all the antimatter what we have created until now, could not light a bulb for a minute. And there is not even the slightest experimental result about that proton decay would be ever possible. It is quite possible that it is impossible. :-)
The mass of the Earth is $6\cdot10^{24} \mathrm{kg}$, its energy equivalent is $\approx 10^{20}$ years of total energy consumption of the humanity.
If there is no proton decay, but we can play with nuclei as we want
If there is no proton decay, then have a fixed amount of protons. They have the least energetic state if they are grouped as iron nuclei (actually a nickel isotope is yet more lesser but the difference is minimal).
Most of the nuclei of the Earth are already iron nuclei, or they are energitcally close to it (like Silicon). But not all. It would be much more hard to calculate the energy, I think it might be only $\approx 10^{16}$ years.
If we can not play with atoms as we want, but we have fusion
Then we can use the deuterium content of the world ocean for energy production. It will be enough only for some millions years.

Thanks. This is the ultimate answer. However, it the though experiment starts with todays tech, the other sources of energy are the core for near term success.

@EdTate I think ordinary nucler energy could be enough until the fusion energy wont be ready. The fusion energy will be likely enough until physicists can not find out this proton decay problem. But, a self-sufficient, nuclear energy based, probably underterrain city should be built and its costs... I am not sure, how big must be a country for complete self-sustainance. I suspect sometimes ten millions of people, and they need some decades. Note, the economical side of the North Korean juche ideology (20million) is exactly this, and the results are not very fine.

It's easy? You can calculate how long oil refineries will continue operating, and how long chemicals useful for energy generation can be extracted, and how long hydroelectric dams can be used? Most of the energy you're talking about is now and in the foreseeable future inaccessible to humanity, so it's meaningless. @EdTate stated "current technology," so everything you mentioned that isn't possible right now is meaningless. (Geez, Ed... you think this is the "ultimate answer?")

@JBH You can survive on ordinary nuclear energy until the fusion power won't be ready. If it will be ready, then the physicists will have hundreds of thousand years to solve the problem of the induced proton decay. Problem is that an underground autarky must be built yet before the disaster.

That's a lot of assumptions given the sun is gone and the OP stated current technology. How many people are left after the apocalypse? Are there enough to even run a nuclear reactor? Who's digging up the fuel for the reactor? Who's keeping the power lines working? Who's researching fusion when problem #1 is the next meal and problem #2 is staying warm? (No nuclear reactors where I live...) You're oversimplifying the problem enormously and ignoring enough science to violate the [tag:hard-science] tag. Can you prove nuclear fusion can be invented quickly enough? If not....

@GraySheep Where are you going to get fusion fuel? By the time you get the technology working, even if that's the day after the event, the fuel bearing heavy water is going to be frozen ten feet deep or more.

@Ash You put a hole into the frozen soil, put in trotil, BOOOOM, and then you go home with the ice. The technology is about 200 years old. And now you have self-sustaining, high-tech economy in large underground cities.

@JBH You are right - if you have no nuclear reactors, then you will all die. Don't forget to kiss the local greens, for a last time.

@GraySheep The heavy water won't be in the surface ice, that's why I asked the question. Heavy Water is always late to phase changes, it freezes at a slightly elevated temperature and it evaporates at a, relatively quite a lot, higher temperature as well.

@Ash I am sorry but 1:6000 of the water of the Earth is heavy water, and a single frozing would not change this et all. Yes, 1:6000 of the ice will be heavy water. You can melt it, then extract the deuterium from it, and then you can let it eaten by fusion reactors.

@GraySheep None of the bunkers you suggest as initial survivors are within reach of the sea. Also no, heavy water has a higher specific heat capacity than diprotium monoxide so it changes phase after lighter water molecules, thus it's concentration in fjords. The surface ice will be low in heavy water, also the one in 6420 deuterium atoms is not enough, all the fusion reactor designs on the books also require tritium which is significantly rarer and lithium-3 which you need to extract from salt water, salt doesn't get incorporated into the freeze so you'd have to go elsewhere for that.

@Ash 1) there is no essential differene between melting the frozen soil or melting sea ice, not the availability of the ice is the bottleneck in such a situation 2) there is no essential difference from the about 1:6000 and I see no reason for you to clog to 6420 and similar numbers 3) truth core of your statement is that currently self-sustaining D-T fusion is realistic in the close future. Self-sustaining D-D fusion is planned. Fusion related to lithium nuclei is not even planned.

@GraySheep 1 in 6420 is 14% less than 1 in 6000, your lowballing makes the situation significantly less terrible. All current fusion reactor designs are D-T with a reactor lining of Lithium-3 as a neutron multiplier to make the overall energy output worthwhile. Neutron free D-D fusion would be lovely but as of a week ago there wasn't a planned experimental test bed yet let alone something workable.

@Ash Dear Ash, after your first 4 words it is clear that you are only hairsplitting. There is no point to continue this. Our discussion ends now.

@GraySheep So you have no idea how math or fusion works good to know.

@Ash I think you are a loser wanting to harm me on a reason known only for you. And I now let you to hate me alone.

@GraySheep Not at all, I don't know you well enough to dislike you. I dislike the inaccuracy, especially as this was originally a [tag:hard-science] question. If we give people answers that don't match with reality their projects suffer, there are already enough badly written and poorly researched pieces of fiction out there, we shouldn't be contributing to the creation of more.
